# what's wrong with my code converting from decimal to binary using array

Tags: java

Compiled with no error. The DrJava stuck when I run this code. Hope you can help me to solve this problem. Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Binary {

    public static void main(String [ ] args) {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int decimal = getInt(console, "Enter a positive number: ");

        while(decimal < 0) {
            decimal = getInt(console, "Enter a positive number: ");
        }

        int[ ] binary  = convertToBinary(decimal);
        printBinaryArray(binary);
    }

    public static int[ ] convertToBinary(int decimal) {
        int decimalCopy = decimal;
        int len = 0;

        while (decimal != 0 ) {
            decimal = decimal / 2;
            len ++;
            decimal = decimalCopy;
        }

        int[ ] binary = new int[len];
        int index = 0;

        while (decimal != 0) {
            if ((decimal % 2) == 1) { //decimal is odd
                binary[index] = 1;
            } else {
                binary[index] = 0;
            }
            decimal = decimal / 2;
            index ++;
        }
        return binary;
    }

    public static void printBinaryArray(int[] binary) {
        for (int i = binary.length - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
            System.out.println("The binary number is: " + binary[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int getInt(Scanner console, String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        while (!console.hasNextInt()) {
            console.next();
            System.out.println("Not an integer; try again.");
            System.out.print(prompt);
        }

        return console.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: I put the decimal = decimalcopy to the outside of the while loop.And return nothing of the printBinaryArray method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an infinite loop:

```
int decimalCopy = decimal;
int len = 0;
while (decimal != 0 ) { 
      decimal = decimal / 2;
      len ++;
      decimal = decimalCopy;
}
```

I'm not sure why you have `decimalCopy`, I don't see that it's necessary, why not just `decimal /= 2;`?  But since `decimalCopy = decimal` is never modified `decimal = decimalCopy` always keeps `decimal` equal to the initial value thus `decimal` never equals `0`.

Also the second part won't work properly since `decimal = 0` after the first while loop.  Two things:

1. Why not use the knowledge of the length of the array and just use a for loop for computing the digits.
2. If you change the parameter of method `convertToBinary` to `final int decimal` I think this will force you to properly use your `decimalCopy` value.

Comment: It works if I out the decimal = decimalcopy to the outside of the while loop. I just make a copy of that value so after the loop I can still get the original value, because I just use the while loop to get the length of the array.